# how to use pandas list to solve linear equation using numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, linear-algebra

I was hoping to find out how to take two pandas lists and solve for x.

```
list_a = [-1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 0, 1]
list_b = [0.0, 0.0, 1.75, -1.125, 1.0, 0.5, 0.0, -1.25, 1.375, -0.125]
```

for each entry in the list I would like to compute the following:

```
x + list_b = list_a
```

which would then return a list of 10 elements with the result for x.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is a "pandas list"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you convert `list_a` and `list_b` to `numpy.array` you can just solve for `x` using subtraction, which numpy will perform elementwise

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> list_a = np.array([-1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 0, 1])
>>> list_b = np.array([0.0, 0.0, 1.75, -1.125, 1.0, 0.5, 0.0, -1.25, 1.375, -0.125])
>>> x = list_a - list_b
>>> x
array([-1.   ,  1.   , -0.75 ,  0.125,  0.   ,  0.5  ,  1.   ,  0.25 ,  -1.375,  1.125])
```